# case-sensitive string comparison

Tags: c#, .net, string, sorting

I want to sort strings case sensitive: so that if one starts with capital "C" then it should be "bigger" (for example) than the one that starts with "c" but also smaller than the one that starts with "d".

For example, sorted list: "a", "A", "chi", "Che", "Chr"

It is written that String comparison methods are case sensitive by default. But it looks like my understanding of "case sensitive" differs from the default one.

Neither of default methods I tried (`String.CompareTo`, `String.Compare` (with different `StringComparison` values)) gives result I want.

Here is the code I've used for testing:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<String> { "Che", "Chr", "chi", "a", "A" }; 

        // Any other way to sort goes here
        list.Sort((s1, s2) => s1.CompareTo(s2));

        for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Exactly this code gives the result: "a" "A" "Che" "chi" "Chr". So small "c" is standing between to "C"s.

So, the question is: is there any way to achieve the sort order I want (which looks pretty obvious) with any of default methods, without writing my own comparer? Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you would need to write your own comparer, if you do attempt this, remember that the ascii values of capitals are less than lower cases

Comment: Your requirement cannot be achieved using standard string comparison since "ch **i**" will always be "greater than" "Ch **e**".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see other way than writing own comparer because of non-strait logic in terms of string: `a < A < c < C` = `97 < 65 < 99 < 67`.

```
sealed class CustomComparer : Comparer<string>
{
    public override int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(x.Length, y.Length); i++)
        {
            char xc = x[i];
            char yc = y[i];
            if (xc == yc)
                continue;
            char xcLow = char.ToLowerInvariant(xc);
            char ycLow = char.ToLowerInvariant(yc);
            if (xcLow == ycLow)
                return xc < yc ? 1 : -1;
            else
                return xcLow < ycLow ? -1 : 1;
        }
        return x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var list = new List<String> { "Che", "Chr", "chi", "a", "A" };
list.Sort(new CustomComparer()); // a, A, chi, Che, Chr
```

Comment: Ok this is the same as "no default way"

Comment: @acrilige, yes, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to sort by first letter (case sensitive) then by the rest of the word (Case-insensitive).  If that's the case, I'd use something like the following LINQ:

`list.OrderBy (l => l.Substring(0,1)).ThenBy (l => l.ToLower())`

Result:
a 
A 
chi 
Che 
Chr

Comment: No I don't. I want to compare case sensitive by each letter, not just the first one

Answer (score 0):

This comparer seems to do what you are looking for..

```
class MyComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        var sets = x.ToCharArray().Zip(y.ToCharArray(), 
                  (LeftChar, RightChar) => new { LeftChar, RightChar });
        var charsToCompare = sets.FirstOrDefault(c => c.LeftChar != c.RightChar);
        if (charsToCompare == null)
            return 0;
        var lowers = char.ToLower(charsToCompare.LeftChar).CompareTo(char.ToLower(charsToCompare.RightChar));
        if (lowers == 0)
            return charsToCompare.RightChar.CompareTo(charsToCompare.LeftChar);
        else
            return char.ToUpper(charsToCompare.LeftChar).CompareTo(char.ToUpper(charsToCompare.RightChar));
    }
}
```

---

Tested with

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<String> { "Che", "Chr", "chi", "a", "A" };

        // Any other way to sort goes here
        list.Sort(new MyComparer());
       // list.Sort((s1, s2) => s1.CompareTo(s2));

        for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}



Output

a
A
chi
Che
Chr
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6883c06%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method for sorting strings

`string.Compare` instead of `a.CompareTo`.

```
String.Compare("Foo", "foo", StringComparison.InvariantCulture)
```

will return true, giving you the sort order you desire.

Applied to your example:

```
list.Sort((s1, s2) => string.Compare(s1, s2, StringComparison.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: I didn't -1, but this is a weak answer. It is basically a link. Can you say with confidence this will solve the problem? If not this should be a comment.

Comment: Of course it fixes it. But official documentation explains a lot better than i can - unless i copy paste the page. the fact that it didn't work means he did something wrtong :D

Comment: @Patrick If you are so confident then you should provide a code snippet to show what you are actually advising. There are also online code compilers that let you run code. Don't be upset if I don't take your word for it that "of course it fixes it".

Comment: you're right. now someone edited my answer, making it into something wrong invariantcultureignorecase? it could be me, but i think it's kinda rude to edit someones answer, especially if he's actively in discussion :D

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what the OP wants. Sorting the list case insensitive results in `a,A,Che,chi,Chr`. But the OP wants `a,A,chi,Che,Chr`.

Comment: This answer is in fact incorrect.  When applied to the list in the OP, it yields the same ordering as with `CompareTo(...)`, which was explicitly stated as undesired.  For it to qualify, you should have at least tested with "Che" and "chi", which was the mis-ordering from the original answer.